# Failed to get D-Bus connection: connection refused

Tags: centos, systemctl

I'm having a hard issue on a server, and I get no clue of what is happening nor where to search to debug it.

Here is my problem :
When I run any command such as :

```
systemctl start httpd.service
```

or

```
systemctl -a
```

or (apparently) any systemctl linked command, I get the following message :

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Connexion refusée
```

Running `ps ax | grep dbus` returns:

```
403   ?     Zs 33:44 [dbus-daemon] <defunct>
25673 pts/2 S+ 0:00  grep --color=auto dbus
```

If you have any clue on it, let me know ! thanks

Comment: Well, I did not want to do it, but a hard reboot made it. (I couldn't reboot with command line though)

Comment: this is not a duplicate.... the other answer is about docker and I'm not using it!